# Get table in ArcPy object

Tags: arcpy, raster, arcobjects, table

I would like to get the output of `StackProfile()` into an ArcPy object to avoid writing files. As far as I know this is possible to do with geometry objects but I have not found a way to do it for tables or rasters. Yes, I have found how to pass a file both raster and table to object, but precisely what I want to avoid is writing the file, that is, obtaining the output directly in an object, since it will only be used for intermediate purposes.

For example, I can get the output of geometry tools in a python object as follows:

```
geometries = arcpy.CopyFeatures_management('c:/temp/outlines.shp', arcpy.Geometry())
```

I would like to know if it is possible to obtain in a similar way:

```
tableOutput = arcpy.ddd.StackProfile(Input,InputTIN,ValueTable())
```

Or for raster:

```
rasterOutput = arcpy.ddd.TinRaster(InputTIN,Raster(), "FLOAT", "LINEAR", "CELLSIZE 1", 1)
```

Comment: Write to the [memory workspace](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/analysis/geoprocessing/basics/the-in-memory-workspace.htm)?  `tableOutput = arcpy.ddd.StackProfile(Input,InputTIN, 'memory/out_table')` and `rasterOutput = arcpy.ddd.TinRaster(InputTIN, 'memory/out_raster', "FLOAT", etc...)`

Comment: @user2856 has a good suggestion, but note specifically what it supports: `memory is a new memory-based workspace developed for ArcGIS Pro that supports output feature classes, tables, and raster datasets.`

Comment: If you're in ArcGIS desktop you can use 'in_memory' instead of 'memory' for the in memory workspace.

Comment: Also as a side note you should understand what a [result object](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-classes/result.htm) is as that is what `geometries` and `tableOutput` are in your examples. Geoprocessing tools return result objects